# Change the dimension of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number of images that have shapes (10,1134,1135). I am trying to change the shape to (10,1134,1134). I converted the image into NumPy and use the array. reshape but I get an error saying cannot reshape the array of size 12870900 into shape (10,1134,1134). Is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: An array of `(10,1134,1135)` to `(10,1134,1134)` would require a loss of data and therefore isn't considered reshaping the array.

Comment: Then are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to shrink the size of your array you need a to drop a vector on some axis of data. There are a few ways to do this through slicing.

**Example Array:**

```
arr = np.zeros((10,1134,1135))
np.shape(arr)

#output
(10, 1134, 1135)
```

---

**Drop First:**

```
new_arr=arr[:,:,1:]
np.shape(new_arr)

#output
(10, 1134, 1134)
```

---

**Drop Last:**

```
new_arr=arr[:,:,0:1134]
np.shape(new_arr)

#output
(10, 1134, 1134)
```

---

**Drop Chosen:**

```
arr_not=list(range(0, np.shape(arr)[2]))
arr_not.remove(9) #choose by index

new_arr=arr[:,:,arr_not]
np.shape(new_arr)

#output
(10, 1134, 1134)
```

You can also use  `np.delete()` as follows:

```
new_arr=np.delete(arr, [134], 2) #choose by index
np.shape(new_arr)

#output
(10, 1134, 1134)
```

[np.delete() documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)